# error int the Failed to set referrer policy

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, meta, referrer-policy

I'm getting the following error in my chrome console for a Wordpress site I'm working on.

> Failed to set referrer policy: The
>   value 'http://example.com/comic/' is not one of 'always', 'default',
>   'never', 'no-referrer', 'no-referrer-when-downgrade', 'origin',
>   'origin-when-crossorigin', or 'unsafe-url'. The referrer policy has
>   been left unchanged.

It's reffereing to this line in the `<head>` of the HTML document...

```
<meta name="Referrer" content="http://example.com/comic/" />
```

I'm vieing the page over `http`, not `https`.

What is causing this issue and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 32):

Go into your .htaccess file and change the following:

```
Header set Referrer-Policy ""
```

to

```
Header set Referrer-Policy "origin"
```

That should fix the issue.

The reason is more than likely because you don’t have correct permissions on your .htaccess file that allows w3tc to make the changes it needs to.

Answer (score 10):

Here 's the definition taken from the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/referrer-policy/):

> A referrer policy modifies the algorithm used to populate the Referer header when fetching subresources, prefetching, or performing navigations.
>   Every environment settings object has an algorithm for obtaining a referrer policy, which is used by default for all requests with that environment settings object as their request client.

**Therefore Referral policy deals with what information (related to the url) the browser ships to a server to retrieve an external resource.**

The options for the `content` attribute listed in the specs are :

- `no-referrer` which specifies that no referrer information is to be sent along with requests made from a particular request client to any origin. The header will be omitted entirely.
- `no-referrer-when-downgrade` doesn't send Referrer header to non [priori authenticated url](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-mixed-content/#a-priori-authenticated-url) (if an https url links to an http url no header is sent)
- `same-origin` policy specifies that a full URL, stripped for use as a referrer, is sent as referrer information when making same-origin requests from a particular request client. while Cross-origin requests won't contain referrer information.
- `origin` sends the scheme, host, and port (basically, the subdomain) stripped of the full URL as a referrer, i.e. https://moz.com/example.html would simply send https://moz.com for all.
- `origin-when-cross-origin` sends the format described in `origin` to cross-origin, while a full stripped URL is sent to same origin requests.
- `unsafe-url` policy specifies that a full URL, stripped for use as a referrer, is sent along with both cross-origin requests and same-origin requests made from a particular request client.
  it's unsafe because it  will leak origins and paths from TLS-protected resources to insecure origins.
- The empty string "" corresponds to no referrer policy, causing a fallback to a referrer policy defined elsewhere, or in the case where no such higher-level policy is available, defaulting to `no-referrer-when-downgrade`.
- `always` behaves like `unsafe-url`.

Comment: Note there is basic browser support for some of these values, particularly same-origin, strict-origin and strict-origin-when-cross-origin when included in a http header - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Just in case if you are here but your `referrer policy` looks fine but your URL contains `google-ad-words` or something social, then ad-blocker might be the culprit. try disabling it.

Answer (score 10):

you can manually find and change as following in .htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Referrer-Policy ""
</IfModule>
```

to

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Referrer-Policy "origin"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: it's working for me. upvote from my side

Answer (score 10):

Chrome Inspection Console showed me the same Error for my Wordpress sites which have W3 Total Cache installed.
    "Failed to set referrer policy: The value '' is not one of 'no-referrer', 'no-referrer- 
     when-downgrade', 'origin', 'origin-when-cross-origin'"

and I tried to update the .htaccess file as indicated in the above answer. This fixed the Chrome Inspection Console error but it returned a few moments later.

Checking the Dashboard of W3 Total Cache Performance ->Browser Cache-> Referrer Policy-> Directive, this entry was showing blank.

Selecting 'origin' from the dropdown resulted in .htaccess being updated with the same value 'origin'
[image: W3 Total Cache Pluginn Console]

Answer (score 1):

"Referer" as a header is spelled without the double R. Maybe with the double R, it's matching against a different header than the one you mean.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `www.` was missing in the API URL, while `www.` was present on the form page. Just ensure your API URL has `www.` if your page has it too.